# Saving an audio file as a ring tone

Tags: 8.0, email, ringtone

On my WP8 Nokia phone, I have received a audio file ring tone in an email and in a text which I sent to myself from my old phone.

How do I save it to be able to use as ring tone?

Answer (score 3):

Technically, you should be able to just "Save as ringtone" when you tap and hold the attachment:

> [Add ringtones to my phone](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/how-to/wp8/start/add-ringtones-to-my-phone)
>
> To add a ringtone from a text message
>   1. Tap and hold the ringtone file, and then tap Save as ringtone.
>   2. Rename the ringtone, if you want to, then tap OK.

If your phone doesn't give you that option, then it's possible (probable) that the file isn't in a format that WP8 supports - WP7 for example [only supported .wma and .mp3 formatted audio](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp7/start/create-ringtones).

Alternatively, you can try to do it from your PC. Ringtones on WP8 need to be saved in the `Ringtones` folder on your phone there are further details on this howto:

> [Sync music, ringtones, and podcasts using my computer](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/how-to/wp8/music/sync-music-ringtones-and-podcasts-using-my-computer)

Answer (score 1):

First the file you want to use as a ring tone must fit the following [requirements](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp7/start/create-ringtones):

- In MP3 or WMA format.
- Less than 40 seconds.
- Less than 1 MB.
- Not protected with digital rights management (DRM).

And most importantly the item that most people miss in the linked article is that the **genre tag** in the song itself be classified as **ringtone**.

Answer (score 1):

Save it like plain mp3 file and then use [Ringtone Maker](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/ringtone-maker/5a99cbd9-e82a-4892-8264-17a64f9142e5) to transform it into ringtone.

[image]

> With Ringtone Maker, you can create ringtones from the music on your phone. Simply open the app, select your favorite song and save it as a ringtone. You can cut your ringtone anyway you like, with editing controls that let you choose the start, end and length of your ringtone.
>
> There’s now support for more music file formats: WMA, M4A, M4R, and AAC along with MP3.